# funny looking comments - c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

when i read through source files of opensource projects i often come across some weird phrases in the comments

```
/*       
@brief ......  
@usage.....  
@remarks....  
@par....  
*/
```

**questions**
1.What are they?(were not mentioned when i was learning c++)
2.Do they have any documentation(where)

Comment: Though, Doxygen comments are actually marked  with /** or /// instead of /* and //

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are just comments and as such have no special meaning in C++. They are probably to allow a documentation generator (For example [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)) to extract the data from the comments.

Answer (score 7):

Those are for some flavour of automatic documentation generator.  Another program runs through the code looking for comments of like you see there.  The `@...` keywords identify how the documentation should be laid out, and that program generates pretty HTML or printed documentation directly from the source code.  It's a way to keep the docs up-to-date with the code more easily.